# Кнопка sumbit передающая данные в output и умножение на десятичные

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как сделать кнопку (sumbit), которая при нажатии передавала результаты в РЕЗУЛЬТАТ (output)? Или же, чтобы можно было нажимать на сам РЕЗУЛЬТАТ (output) и на выходе получать подсчёт данных.

Если во всех полях пусто, то output = NAN, как исправить ?

Так же, не понятно, почему удаётся умножать только целые числа.

```
<input name="c" value="1,5" class="input-form" placeholder="K">
```

При расчёте учитывается как единица.

```html
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*(parseInt(b.value)/100)*parseInt(c.value)">

  <input name="a" value="400" class="input-form" placeholder="CPL">

  <input name="b" value="3" class="input-form" placeholder="CV1">

  <input name="c" value="1,5" class="input-form" placeholder="K">

  <output name="x" for="a b c" class="input-form" placeholder="">РЕЗУЛЬТАТ</output>

</form>
```

Comment: _Так же, не понятно, почему удаётся умножать только целые числа._: вы используете _parseInt_ для всех полей - который возвращает целое число

Comment: _Если во всех полях пусто, то output = NAN_, а какой результат вы ожидаете. если поля пустые?

Comment: про parseInt уже прочёл.
а что использовать в качестве альтернативы?

Хотелось бы, чтобы выводило 0

Comment: в моём случае подходит parseFloat

Comment: а также функция [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения из строки дробного значения используется функция [*parseFloat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

для подставки нуля в случае неудачного преобразования, можно использовать логическую операцию [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

```html
<form oninput="x.value=(parseFloat(a.value)||0)*((parseFloat(b.value)||0)/100)*(parseFloat(c.value)||0)">

  <input name="a" value="400" class="input-form" placeholder="CPL">

  <input name="b" value="3" class="input-form" placeholder="CV1">

  <input name="c" value="1.5" class="input-form" placeholder="K">

  <output name="x" for="a b c" class="input-form" placeholder="">РЕЗУЛЬТАТ</output>

</form>
```

**Обратите внимание:** разделитель дробной части - точка, а не запятая.